# Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener - Junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, powermock

we upgraded the `springboot` version `2.5.14` to `2.7.5` , all of a sudden the below `junit`
started failing.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class StarterApplicationTest {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(SpringApplication.class)
    public void testMain(){
        mockStatic(SpringApplication.class);
        StarterApplication.main(new String[0]);
        verifyStatic(SpringApplication.class);
        SpringApplication.run(StarterApplication.class);

    }

}
```

with the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@37e20a89 failed.

Comment: Please let me know if any other information required. I tried many other options like 'MockitoJunitRunner.class' , 'SpringRunner' etc. this issue is completely blocking the deployment

Comment: By any chance are you using Junit 4?